# Prototype: Change attribute

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

How can I change a `<img>` with the JS-Library Prototype?
I managed it to get the element but I couldn't change the "src":

```
$('item1').getElementsBySelector('img')
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var imgs = $('item1').getElementsBySelector('img');
imgs.each(function(img) {
    img.src = 'newSrc';
});
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also use the setAttribute function.

```
var imgs = $('item1').getElementsBySelector('img');
imgs.each(function(img) {
    img.setAttribute('src','newSrc');
    img.setAttribute('width','100px');
});
```